# Open application in specific workspace

Tags: perl, unix, workspace

I am trying to open gmemusage in a specific workspace using unix; however, gmem doesn't accept the -xrm parameter. Is ther another method that can use to accomplish this?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#use strict;
$ENV{DISPLAY} = "$1:0.0";
#system('xlogo -xrm "*workspaceList: Two"');     #<--- This works
system('gmemusage -xrm "*workspaceList: Two"');  #<--- This does not work
sub testSystemScript{
    if( $? == -1)
    {
        die("Command failed: $!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Linux window managers myself (I use a Mac), but I did a little googling and found [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/how-to-specify-a-gnome-workpace-an-application-will-launch-in-555764/). If I understand it correctly, I think you should be able to do:

```
system('wmctrl -s Two; gmemusage');
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I need the wmctrl library for that to work... I am not allowed to download any libraries.

Comment: Hmm, none of the web sites I found when I google wmctrl say anything about it requiring other software. I assumed it came with any window managers that it's compatible.

Comment: I downloaded it, it's just a single C program, no library required.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about `gmemusage` and `xlogo`, but I do know about Perl's special variables. Did you mean to use [`$ARGV[0]`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#@ARGV) instead of [`$1`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#digits)?

```
$ENV{DISPLAY} = "$ARGV[0]:0.0";
```

Comment: This seems like it should be a comment, since it's orthogonal to the question.

Comment: @mob No, I meant to use $1. I can try ARGV[0] next time though.

Comment: If the OP needs the `DISPLAY` var to be set according to a command-line argument instead of a regular expression match (which is not shown in the OP), then this might be the right answer to the question. And if not, then it's the wrong answer to the question.

Comment: He's not asking about setting display, he's asking about controlling which workspace within the display is used -- he needs a substitute for the `-xrm` option that other applications recognize.

Comment: Like I said, I don't know much about `gmemusage` etc. But I infer from the fact that the OP included `$ENV{DISPLAY}=...` in the question that it's important. And from the fact that the OP mentions `$1` but doesn't show a regex, that the OP is confused about Perl's variables. I could be wrong about either of these.